# Assign a new value to a specified column in a table

Tags: dolphindb

Assign a new value to a specified column in a table

Which function can be used to assign a new value to a specified column? Take an example: I have a table names t. If I query a element in row1 and column0, I can invoke t.cell(1, 0). But seems it doesn't support the operation t.cell(1, 0)=2. How to assign 2 to t.cell(1, 0)?

Answer (score 1):

The sample code is as follows:

```py
t=table(1..5 as id, 6..10 as v)
t[`id,1]=11
```

| id | v |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 11 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 5 | 10 |